# How to convert canvas to SVG with embedded image base64 in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html, svg, fabricjs

I have fabricjs canvas with image, which I loaded by `fabric.Image.fromURL()` method.

I need export it to SVG, but I want to export image as embedded source in base64, not as a link.

How can I do it? Is it any way to load image as a source not as a link?

Example code:

**Loading image:**

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('./assets/people.jpg', function (image) {
    image.set({
        left: 10,
        top: 30
    });
    canvas.add(image);
};
```

**Exporting to SVG:**

```
canvas.toSVG();
```

**In exported SVG I have:**

```
<image xlink:href="http://localhost:8383/app/assets/people.png" />
```

**But I want it in base64 like:**

```
<image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAe8AAAKuCAYAAACIZZSZAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACx(...)" />
```

Comment: I don't know if there is a direct option in fabricjs, but it wouldn't be to hard to write it yourself: parse the URL, load the image, draw it to a new canvas resized with image's dimension, replace the URL with this canvas' toDataURL result.

Comment: I was looking for a direct option in fabricjs, but if it doesn't exist, I have to write it myself. Thanks Kaiido for your advice, I will implement your approach.

Comment: After a quick search in the fabricjs' docs, I couldn't find any options. But something that came to my mind afterward is that you could actually directly convert your image to a dataURI and pass this dataURI to fabricjs, I guess it would work and avoids the parsing thing. Also, some SO users do participate in the development of fabricjs, so lets hope they see your post, and include this option in a future version. (even if I can see the cross-origin limitations as a no-go in such a library)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no option but you can easily achieve it like this:
Image has a method that is called 'getSvgSrc';

override it like this:

```
fabric.Image.prototype.getSvgSrc = function() {
  return this.toDataURLforSVG();
};

fabric.Image.prototype.toDataURLforSVG = function(options) {
  var el = fabric.util.createCanvasElement();
        el.width  = this._element.naturalWidth || this._element.width;
        el.height = this._element.naturalHeight || this._element.height;
  el.getContext("2d").drawImage(this._element, 0, 0);
  var data = el.toDataURL(options);
  return data;
};
```

In this way you should be able to obtain an integrated image for the svg.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the toSVG method :

```
rasterizeSVG () {
    let w = window.open('')
    w.document.write(this.canvas.toSVG())
    return 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(this.canvas.toSVG())
  }
```

or :

```
rasterize() {
  if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
    alert('This browser doesn\'t provide means to serialize canvas to an image');
  }
  else {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = this.canvas.toDataURL('png')
    var w = window.open("");
    w.document.write(image.outerHTML);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ouzza, I have the same problem, but proving your example I've found that it works but not like I hope. I just need the image in the same view Canvas and Image, can you help me (in your example with Angular)?

Comment: Hi @jecorrales i ' m sorry i didn't respond sooner.
could you explain your problem .

Comment: by the way the two examples are working fine in both vuejs and angular

Comment: Yes, thanks for that... I could to find the solution with other way. But, your example is good, it works for me!