# Convert fabricjs canvas to base64 image

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to send a canvas as an image to my server and I want to send as base64. 
Fabricjs offers using `canvas.toSVG()` or `canvas.toDataURL({format: 'image/png'})` to convert the canvas to an image however the output on my log appears to be a Klass object (first time seeing that) and upon sending that object to the server and logging what's received on the server I get an empty object or a path i.e:

```
{ version: '2.0.0-rc.3', objects: [] }
{ version: '2.0.0-rc.3',
  objects: 
   [ { type: 'path',
       version: '2.0.0-rc.3',
       originX: 'left',
       originY: 'top',
       left: 156.21249771118164,
       top: 221.20000457763672,
       width: 132,
       height: 53,
       fill: null,
       stroke: 'Red',
       strokeWidth: 10,
       strokeDashArray: null,
       strokeLineCap: 'round',
       strokeLineJoin: 'round',
       strokeMiterLimit: 10,
       scaleX: 1,
       scaleY: 1,
       angle: 0,
       flipX: false,
       flipY: false,
       opacity: 1,
       shadow: null,
       visible: true,
       clipTo: null,
       backgroundColor: '',
       fillRule: 'nonzero',
       paintFirst: 'fill',
       globalCompositeOperation: 'source-over',
       transformMatrix: null,
       skewX: 0,
       skewY: 0,
       path: [Object] } ] }
```

Klass object console image:

[image]

My code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas();
canvas.loadFromJSON(val[i].story); //val has saved canvas
canvas.toSVG(); //or to dataURL()
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117810/how-to-convert-canvas-to-svg-with-embedded-image-base64-in-fabricjs) and still the same klass object, need to convert the canvas to base64 image (png preferred) and send to the server where I'll be converting to an image file, thanks.

Comment: This thing is not possible. toDataUrl gives you a string and so does toSVG. please some code, so we can check better. Are you running under nodejs? what version of fabricjs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was missing the id of the canvas when creating the canvas hence

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasID');
```